# "HOW TO KEEP FORMATTING ON A SPECIFIC CELL/ROW (USING SORT FUNCTION) AFTER NEW DATA IS ENTERED"

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'd really appreciate some help with the document.
I'm using the auto sort (SORT function) on the second sheet and would like to keep the conditional formatting to a certain cell/row after a box is checked - even when/after new data are entered. (I'm sending a link to the document below.)

To be more exact. When I enter new data on the 1st tab ("MAIN ENTRY PAGE") the data is auto-sorted on the 2nd tab ("AUTOSORT BY DATE"). I'd like to have an option on the 2nd tab that after the box is checked, the row changes colour. the issue now is that AFTER NEW DATA IS ENTERED  - the formatting remains on the same cell.
example: If I check the box on the first entry (16.3.2023) on the "AUTOSORT BY DATE" tab and later add a new date on "MAIN ENTRY PAGE" (15.3.2023) the row on the 15th is marked as checked - I'd like to keep the formatting to the previously checked row (16.3.2023).

LINK: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vx6V8FMDzFTQNvkb-YEolIv4e_SvbaQ6O7AVxyB97bE/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be really useful.

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications.  If you use the state of the first column to determine your conditional formatting for each row, then re-sort all the rows with the exception of the first column, it goes to reason that the relationship between the first column and the rest of the data would break.    Do you expect the checkboxes to remain on one line but the formatting to switch to another?  Please see [How to ask a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  Please reformat the title to remove quotes and include proper sentence case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't link checkboxes manually entered with data imported and sorted by formula. I suggest you work everything in the same tab but using "Filter Views". I suggest you look into them, you'll be able to sign between different views and sorting, but always working with the original data (including that extra column with the checkboxes)

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop